# How can I have a specific tab refreshed on post in Asp.Net Core Razor tabbed pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a tabbed Razor page, on load there is no data to be retrieved from server, active tab set for first tab. However, when I update data on one tab and post it I want the page to get only data for that tab. What I have so far is

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="PTWTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="PTW-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#PTW" aria-controls="ptw" aria-selected="true" style="width:200px">Permit To Work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="HazId-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#HazId" aria-controls="hazid" aria-selected="false" style="width:200px">Hazard Identification</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="GasTest-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#GasTest" aria-controls="gt" aria-selected="false" style="width:200px">Gas Testing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="IsoCert-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#IsoCert" aria-controls="isocert" aria-selected="false" style="width:200px">Isolation Certificate</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and cshtml is:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostIsoCertAsync(int? PTWNo)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        var newIsoCert = await _context.ICContents.FindAsync(PTWNo);

        if (newIsoCert == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<ICContent>(
                     newIsoCert,
                     "ICContent",
                       c => c.IdICD,
                       c => c.IsoStep,
                       c => c.EquipmentID,
                       c => c.EquipmentDescription,
                       c => c.EnSource,
                       c => c.IsType,
                       c => c.IsMethod,
                       c => c.LockNo,
                       c => c.PreparedBy,
                       c => c.ImplementedBy,
                       c => c.VerifiedBy,
                       c => c.IsStatus))
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            
            return Page();
        }

        return Page();
    }
```

there is also an OnGet procedure and html to display data

Comment: my OnGet code is: public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetIsoCertAsync(int ptwNoId)
       ...code here
            
            return Page();
        }

Comment: If you want just just sections of your html changed, in this case tab, you will have to write JavaScript. Your action method should return a partial view for ease of work. When you send a request to the action method and it returns it's result, JavaScript can then replace the specific area of the page you want to replace with the partial view that was returned

Comment: I just wanted to avoid javascript and only update the tab that concern me. On partial view I didn't explore yet but is related to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I update data on one tab and post it I want the page to get only data for that tab.

If you'd like to just update a specific tab section content, as @Tavershima mentioned, you can try to dynamically render some partial view using Ajax on JavaScript. The following simple demo is for your reference.

```
@page
@model WebGlobalSearch.MenuTabModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MenuTab";
}

<h1>MenuTab</h1>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="PTWTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="PTW-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#PTW" aria-controls="ptw" aria-selected="true" style="width:200px">Permit To Work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="HazId-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#HazId" aria-controls="hazid" aria-selected="false" style="width:200px">Hazard Identification</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="GasTest-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#GasTest" aria-controls="gt" aria-selected="false" style="width:200px">Gas Testing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="IsoCert-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#IsoCert" aria-controls="isocert" aria-selected="false" style="width:200px">Isolation Certificate</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="PTW" class="tab-pane fade active show">
        <h3>Permit To Work</h3>
        <br />
        <div class="tab-c">
            <partial name="PTW" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="HazId" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Hazard Identification</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="GasTest" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Gas Testing</h3>
        <br />
        <div class="tab-c">
            <partial name="GasTest" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="IsoCert" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Isolation Certificate</h3>
    </div>
</div>

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@section scripts{
    <script>
        function UpdateGasTestFunc() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                url: "MenuTab?handler=UpdateGasTest",
                //data: data,
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#GasTest").find("div.tab-c").html(res);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

*OnPostUpdateGasTest handler*

```
public IActionResult OnPostUpdateGasTest()
{
    return Partial("GasTest");
}
```

*Content of partial view `GasTest`*

```
Gas Testing Page @DateTime.Now.ToString()


<input type="button" value="Update" id="btn_update" onclick="UpdateGasTestFunc()" />
```

*Test Result*

[image]

> I just wanted to avoid javascript and only update the tab that concern me

Under the scenario you described in your question, normally if browser user submit updated data to server without from JavaScript, server would return new response to browser client and full page will be re-rendered, not just a part of html content.

***Update:***

> What I want is to post, refresh page and show the tab I post from

To dynamically reset active tab after page reloaded, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
$(function () {
    var active_tab_id = localStorage.getItem('activetab');

    if (active_tab_id != null) {
        //console.log(active_tab_id);
            $('#PTWTab a[id="' + active_tab_id + '"]').tab('show');
    }
           
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        //console.log($(e.target).attr("id")); 
        localStorage.setItem('activetab', $(e.target).attr('id'));
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you Fei Han, I will give it a try

Comment: Yes, you can create a simple demo to test the approach that we mentioned first, then if it can achieve the requirement, you can apply it within your project.

Comment: I get error on partial view for PTW. Also, where do I put GasTest partial view?

Comment: 1) `get error on partial view` What's the error? 2) `where do I put GasTest partial view? ` I prefer to put in Shared folder.

Comment: it doesn't find the PTW

Comment: Do you create a partial view named PTW? If not, please comment out this line `<partial name="PTW" />`.

Comment: Ok, I got your model to work, so far so good. Now I will include my stuff. Let's see. Shall I use IList instead on @foreach? for partial view model?

Comment: Now I will have the main view containing a form to post mixed with a partial view. OnPost will save data and retrieve as partial view from server. Does it make sense what I say?

Comment: How do I post from javascript and keep active tab visible?

Comment: `How do I post from javascript and keep active tab visible?` posting data from javascript would not cause page refreshing and active tab reset, what's the problem now?

Comment: Well, in each tab I have to add data with a Submit button. So if I am on one Tab, I fill data and post a form, the data is written to the server and then displayed. I have both post and display div's on the same tab. This I can do. What I want is to post, refresh page and show the tab I post from

Comment: `What I want is to post, refresh page and show the tab I post from` The question now is how to keep previous active tab after posting form data? To achieve it, you can store a flag (active tab index or name) in localStorage or cookie, then dynamically check it and reset active tab based on stored flag with javascript code.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Hi @NMariusV, please check my new update with code snippet to dynamically set active tab.

Comment: Excellent, now it's resolved, thank you very much for your help